# MySQL: Self join table offset by one row (equiv to T-SQL CTE with ROW_NUMBER())

Tags: mysql

As the title suggests, in **MySQL**, I want to join a table to itself, offset by 1 row so that I can calculate the time between rows for DateTime fields.

In T-SQL this would be done using ROW_NUMBER() and CTE.

Comment: The data may allow for alternative methods. I suggest providing a sample of your data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

row_number can be simulated in mysql using variable(s). For example given
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from dates limit 10;

```
+------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
| id   | dte        | CalMonth | CalMonthDescLong | CalMonthDescShort | calQtr |
+------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
|    1 | 2000-01-01 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    2 | 2000-01-02 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    3 | 2000-01-03 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    4 | 2000-01-04 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    5 | 2000-01-05 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    6 | 2000-01-06 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    7 | 2000-01-07 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    8 | 2000-01-08 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|    9 | 2000-01-09 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
|   10 | 2000-01-10 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |
+------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

this query

```
select s.*
        ,t.dte,t.rownumber1
from 
(
select d.*,@rn:=@rn+1 rownumber from 
(select @rn:=0) rn,dates d
) s
join
(
select d.*,@rn1:=@rn1+1 rownumber1 from 
(select @rn1:=0) rn,dates d
) t on t.rownumber1 = s.rownumber + 1
limit 10
```

Returns

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id   | dte        | CalMonth | CalMonthDescLong | CalMonthDescShort | calQtr | rownumber | dte        | rownumber1 |
+------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 2000-01-01 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         1 | 2000-01-02 |          2 |
|    2 | 2000-01-02 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         2 | 2000-01-03 |          3 |
|    3 | 2000-01-03 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         3 | 2000-01-04 |          4 |
|    4 | 2000-01-04 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         4 | 2000-01-05 |          5 |
|    5 | 2000-01-05 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         5 | 2000-01-06 |          6 |
|    6 | 2000-01-06 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         6 | 2000-01-07 |          7 |
|    7 | 2000-01-07 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         7 | 2000-01-08 |          8 |
|    8 | 2000-01-08 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         8 | 2000-01-09 |          9 |
|    9 | 2000-01-09 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |         9 | 2000-01-10 |         10 |
|   10 | 2000-01-10 |        1 | January          | Jan               |      1 |        10 | 2000-01-11 |         11 |
+------+------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

There are loads of other examples on SO which might suit you better.